# How do I instantiate local inner class with reflection in Java?

Tags: java

I accessed local inner class by reflection, but why can't I instantiate the class?

```
public class Demo {

    public static Object show(){
        class Outer{
            int num = 20;
        }
        return new Outer();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object o = show();
        System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
        Object o1 = o.getClass().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. You just have to wrap the last line `bject o1 = o.getClass().newInstance();` in a try/catch block

Comment: If you want to use the object out of the method ,you'd better not define it  in a method